# Why doesn't "set -P" work after a pipe?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, set, pipe

```
C:\>type c:\output.txt
abcd
C:\>type c:\output.txt | set /p V1=

C:\>set
... A bunch of junk, NOT seeing "V1"
```

What happened? According to all documentation for `SET` I've seen, %V1% should have been assigned a value of "abcd" from the above, no?

I'm on Windows XP Pro, SP3 if it matters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The pipe seems to create a new CMD instance to carry out the next command that is receiving the pipe data.  So when the pipe has concluded, that CMD instance exits and the variable is lost.

Comment: Coincidentally, I needed to take a number from the stdout of one program, do some math on it, and then pipe it to another for usage.  This seems to do the trick:

echo 5|(set /P TmpVar= && set /a TmpVar/2)>C:\test.txt

Comment: +1; Indeed the problem is a result of how Windows implements pipes. See [Why does delayed expansion fail when inside a piped block of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/1012053) for a full explanation of the mechanism, along with many interesting side effects.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what doco *you've* seen for the `set` command but the output of `set /?` clearly states:

> The /P switch allows you to set the value of a variable to a line of input entered *by the user.*

(my italics). I think `set /p` is getting its input from the console regardless of what you're trying to pipe in through standard input. Why it's not waiting, I'm not sure. `echo xxx | set /p xx=` also fails to set the variable.

But, if you want to set a variable from a single line file, you can just use one of these:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (c:\output.txt) do set V1=%%i
set /p V1=<c:\output.txt
```

That second one is the simplest but it doesn't help much if you want to grab the output of an arbitrary command but you may well have to direct it to a file first.

The first one allows you to execute arbitrary commands *without* temporary files:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('echo AAA') do set xx=%%i
```

---

There's an interesting snippet on [this page](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=104) which suggests it has to do with contexts:

> Ok, I found out why myself. It's because the `|` creates a new context so the variable never makes it out to the rest of the current context. Proof:
>   `> set bar=`
>   `> echo aaa | (set /p bar= && set bar)`
>   `bar=aaa`
>   `> set bar`
>   `Environment variable bar not defined`

although I decline to comment on the veracity of that conclusion. I don't know what contexts are in this sense, I'm just bringing it to your attention for completeness.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done any batch coding in over 10 years and thus my head is polluted by Unix notions that STDIN is STDIN ... I guess you are right that "by the user" is not synonymous with "STDIN" in DOS-world by default (yes, I know about wanky TTY detection stuff some Unix programs pull, but that's a rare and hard to achieve exception :)  I will need to read more about these contexts (actually saw that page last night but was too tired to parse it fully.

Comment: Well, I think you're actually right, @DVK, despite my original paragraphs in the above answer. It's clearly _some_ sort of STDIN since `set /p V1=<c:\output.txt` works fine. It's just the pipe variety that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the SET command and everything to do with how Windows implements pipes. See TonyM's answer, as well as the link I put in a comment there.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to the original question, which asked `Why doesn't [..] work?`, but this answer can be useful to people looking to a̲c̲h̲i̲e̲v̲e̲ what would be the *logical result* of something like this:

```
echo:somevalue|set /p somevar=
```

The normal workaround, for example for the code above, would be:

```
echo:somevalue>tempfile.txt&set /p somevar=<tempfile.txt
```

which does the work perfectly, except that it creates a new file which has to be dealt with afterwards (on top of the fact that we need to take extra steps to make sure this new file doesn't overwrite an existing one we didn't create or never intended to replace).

While it is true there is *no way* around using a file stream to bridge the gap across both sides of the pipe `|` operator as far as environment variables are concerned, being under a Windows NT environment, and *provided* the volume the script resides on is using the NTFS filesystem, one can use something far more elegant than temporary files: [**alternate data streams**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29)

Let's jump right into an example illustrating how one might use them:

```
echo:somevalue>".\%~nx0":temp&set /p somevar=<".\%~nx0":temp
```

Here `%~nx0` stands for, and gets expanded to, the **filename** (base name + extension) of our batch file, enclosed in quotes in case it contains spaces.

> **Note:**
>   While one could use `%0` directly (without quotes) instead to refer to
>   the current script, `.\%~nx0` is more manageable if you ever need to
>   look at the expanded value of the command while debugging your script, 
>   especially if the full path of your script is quite long.

As such, `".\%~nx0":temp` refers to an **alternate data stream (ADS)** of our *own* script named `temp`, for example `myscript.cmd:temp`, that we create (or overwrite) with the output of the `echo` command. Since ADS behave the same way as the default stream of a file, the `echo` and `set` commands don't see any difference.

A complete script using the method could look like this:

```
@echo off
set __self=".\%~nx0"
set __adsname=test.dat

:: Using some input...
set l_input=@FirewallAPI.dll,-23000
echo:Input: %l_input%
echo:

:: ...we process it...
expand_str_res_id.exe %l_input%>%__self%:%__adsname%&set /p l_output=< %__self%:%__adsname%

:: ...and show the output, e.g. "File and Printer Sharing"
echo:Output: %l_output%
echo:

:cleanup
set l_input=
set l_output=
type nul> %__self%:%__adsname%
set __self=
set __adsname=
pause
```

Here, at the end of the script, the line `type nul> %__self%:%__adsname`, which could be expanded to something like `type nul> ".\myscript.cmd":test.dat`, is used to clear the content of the alternate data stream we just used. Although this sets the size of the alternate data stream to zero, it does **not** erase it (see notes below).

Some final notes:

1. Most commands cannot understand or work with alternate data streams when they are provided as **source files**. This means the following ones cannot be used:

   - `type`, e.g. `type myscript.cmd:data > myscript_data.txt`
   - `copy`, e.g. `copy myscript.cmd:data myscript_data.txt`
   - `move`, e.g. `move myscript.cmd:data myscript_data.txt`
   - `del`/`erase`, e.g. `del myscript.cmd:data`
   - `ren`/`rename`, e.g. `ren myscript.cmd:data myscript.cmd:data.txt`
   - and so on

   In fact, it's really only file redirection that supports alternate data streams **with one exception** (that I can think of): the `start` command.
2. Although we can quite easily clear/erase the content of an alternate data stream, **deleting one** is quite trickier since copying a file or renaming it does not involve any streams (well `:$DATA` ones), and editing/changing the content of a file only affects the default data stream. Still, we have a few options depending on what we're trying to achieve:

   - If we only have a single alternate data stream *or* don't mind deleting **all** of them at once, and the content of the file is only text, then we can create a new file by keeping **only** the default data stream of the original file using the following command `type myscript.cmd > myscript_clean.cmd`, after which the original file can be deleted.
   - If we have administrative rights on the volume *and* operate under Windows Vista or a later version of the OS, we can use [MKLINK](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) to create a symbolic link to **one** alternate data stream, which will then provide us with a standard filename to be used with the usual file management commands.
   - Alternatively, one can use one of the many tools available to manipulate alternate data streams, like [Streams](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/streams), [LADS](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/LADS), or [AlternateStreamView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/alternate_data_streams.html).
3. A useful command to list regular files *including* alternate data streams from the command line is `dir /a-d /r`. You can then use any program to access the names (alternate) data stream of a file, e.g. `notepad.exe myscript.cmd:data`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To add a brief example of how to confirm the other answers, you can immediately check the contents of the variable on the other side of the pipe using another set command IE:

ECHO HELLO | (set /P hi= && set hi)

Will output

hi=HELLO

But after execution the variables are destroyed : (, so a further 'set hi' will reveal:

Environment variable hi not defined